# OAuth 2.0 Device Authentication Flow - invalid device code

Tags: oauth, iot

I am trying to implement OAuth 2.0 Device Authentication Flow. In first step i received device code successfully. Then i have created JWT token using device code and and other details. Send it to oAuth endpoint as per documentation in my polling request. In response i receive following error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "invalid device code"
}
```

Here are different format of my polling request that i have tried:

```
{
  "grant_type": "device",
  "client_id": "3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAeSesYYnKvM92KLFkRmZwR8mEz_DvAQiN1LLMRClcAcDlsKy44qjwvWCvBWwFvFhVrs5A1",
  "client_secret" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "code": "M01WRzlaTDBwcEdQNVVyQWVTZXNZWW5Ldk05MktMRmtSbVp3UjhtRXpfRHZBUWlOMUxMTVJDbGNBY0Rsc0t5NDRxand2V0N2Qld3RnZGaFZyczVBMTsxMTQuMTQzLjUwLjk1OzE1MzY0NjkyNTQxNjU7N1ZZN1I3N1U"
}
```

Try 2:

```
{
  "grant_type": "device",
  "client_id": "3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAeSesYYnKvM92KLFkRmZwR8mEz_DvAQiN1LLMRClcAcDlsKy44qjwvWCvBWwFvFhVrs5A1",
  "code": "M01WRzlaTDBwcEdQNVVyQWVTZXNZWW5Ldk05MktMRmtSbVp3UjhtRXpfRHZBUWlOMUxMTVJDbGNBY0Rsc0t5NDRxand2V0N2Qld3RnZGaFZyczVBMTsxMTQuMTQzLjUwLjk1OzE1MzY0NjkyNTQxNjU7N1ZZN1I3N1U"
}
```

Try 3:

```
{
  "grant_type": "device",
  "client_id": "3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAeSesYYnKvM92KLFkRmZwR8mEz_DvAQiN1LLMRClcAcDlsKy44qjwvWCvBWwFvFhVrs5A1",
  "device_code": "M01WRzlaTDBwcEdQNVVyQWVTZXNZWW5Ldk05MktMRmtSbVp3UjhtRXpfRHZBUWlOMUxMTVJDbGNBY0Rsc0t5NDRxand2V0N2Qld3RnZGaFZyczVBMTsxMTQuMTQzLjUwLjk1OzE1MzY0NjkyNTQxNjU7N1ZZN1I3N1U"
}
```

Try 4

```
{
  "grant_type": "device",
  "client_id": "3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrAeSesYYnKvM92KLFkRmZwR8mEz_DvAQiN1LLMRClcAcDlsKy44qjwvWCvBWwFvFhVrs5A1",
  "devicecode": "M01WRzlaTDBwcEdQNVVyQWVTZXNZWW5Ldk05MktMRmtSbVp3UjhtRXpfRHZBUWlOMUxMTVJDbGNBY0Rsc0t5NDRxand2V0N2Qld3RnZGaFZyczVBMTsxMTQuMTQzLjUwLjk1OzE1MzY0NjkyNTQxNjU7N1ZZN1I3N1U"
}
```

Here is screen shot from postman 
[image: Received device code and other details]
[image: Got error in step 2]

Can anyone please suggest what is correct format of the the request?

Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_device_flow.htm&type=5

https://jwt.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the access token , in the second request you need to pass the following

POST /services/oauth2/token  HTTP/1.1

grant_type=device&client_id="your client id"&code="device code returned in Step 1"

Comment: Thank you! .. I dont know why doc shows the sample as JWT token.